# Can my boss discuss my on going lawsuit with other employees without my knowledge?

Tags: privacy

I was hurt awhile back and I'm going through a lawsuit with this company. Without my knowledge my boss asked another employee if I was doing anything that I wasn't supposed to and began to tell the other employee that I was sueing the company. This other employee was not aware of my lawsuit until my boss told him! Did my boss violate my privacy?

Comment: What country? In USA most lawsuits are very much public record. And you probably should tell that to your lawyer.

Comment: I would say yes, that's definitely a violation of privacy.

Comment: How did your boss find out that you were suing the company?

Comment: @sf02 from OPs description, the boss is checking the validity of the claim by interviewing other employees. A fairly normal thing.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul That is correct but it does not explain how the boss knows about the lawsuit.

Comment: @sf02 If he is investigating he was told to do so by whoever is handling it, can be boss himself, company lawyer, or anyone up the chain. Not that it really matters. I VTC as this is an ongoing lawsuit and I don't know anyone here wants to become part of it, OP needs to speak with his lawyer.

Comment: @Justice That could also be called gathering evidence by the defense team. They do have a right to do that which would include talking to other employees in the company.

Comment: @JoeW I still believe that is a violation of privacy. It's one thing to ask what happened but it's a completely different thing when you discuss that a fellow employee has a lawsuit against the company.

Comment: @Justice So they wouldn't be able to discuss with a coworker what the lawsuit is about and potentially find out that the person is faking what happened so they could win it?

Comment: @JoeW Like I said, you can discuss what happened. The details of a lawsuit should not be discussed with coworkers. Ask what happened, there's no need to inform them of the colleague that's suing the company.

Answer (score 7):

Since you've probably already engaged a lawyer to deal with the lawsuit, you really should be discussing this with them rather than a bunch of strangers on the internet.